# php require_once or include inside HTML head tag does not put the code inside head but in body

Tags: php

I want to share the content of my HTML *head* tag among several pages but I am facing a weird error when I use require_once inside a HTML *head* tag. Let me explain better.

If I have the next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Datos Soluciones Informáticas</title>        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
```

and I inspect the code, everthing looks as expected.

[image]

However, If I move the content of my head tag to a external file /snippets/head.php

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

And then write in my index.php file the next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Datos Soluciones Informáticas</title>        
    <?php require_once('/snippets/head.php'); ?>    
</head>
```

The inspect shows that the code is not inserted in the proper place:

[image]

It is not just the problem that the inspect does not work but the page does not behave as expected. I have the same issue with `include` instead `require_once`

The raw output obtained with view-source:localhost in chrome looks good but the page is not rendered well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Datos Soluciones Informáticas</title>        
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
```

I am using Xampp 6.1 Build 7601 in a Windows 7 machine as my local environment.

Does anyone knows what I am missing?

Comment: This file actually exist? print the contents of head.php too.

Comment: Can you view the raw source for your page?  The DOM inspector shows the DOM tree that the browser generated from the source, and the browser will attempt to clean up invalid markup.  Also, what happens when you feed the output of your script through the W3 HTML validator?

Comment: raw output looks good but there is defenitely something wrong. Because the page is not rendered properly when I have the required_once

Comment: Andrey Knupp, the head.php is just two lines of html as printed in the question

Comment: have you turned error reporting on? There might be an exception somewhere that's messing about.

Comment: @Sergio del Amo: Just replace your 'inspect' screenshots in the question with the equivalent top part of the raw output of the two versions - as stated, inspect shows the generated DOM, which will already contain corrections made by the browser. It is very likely that the messed up rendering results from a small markup error, which can only be judged looking at the raw output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another shot:

Does your included file start with an invisible byte order mark (BOM)? Then remove it by setting the proper character encoding.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php which contains this comment:

> AVOID ZERO BYTE ORDER MARK!
>
> I was having problems with include/require (once or not). I created an include-opening.php which had the initial structure of the page, and then included this page in all other pages. The result was looking "crashed", so I did compare including or just pasting the html code into the page. The hardcoded version displayed ok, even with the source code being exactly the same.
>
> So I opened the include file with notepad++ and set the encoding to UTF-8 (no BOM) and voila, everything is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include file without first slash, like this:

```
<?php require_once('snippets/head.php'); ?>
```