# Google Chrome Audit tool says to put CSS in the document head when it already is

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome Audit tool says:

> Put CSS in the document head (3) CSS in the document body adversely
>   impacts rendering performance. Link node bootstrap-extract.css should
>   be moved to the document head Link node style.css should be moved to
>   the document head Link node css should be moved to the document head

But the stylesheets are linked in the head. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="fr-FR" xml:lang="fr-FR">
<head>
    <title>site</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/bootstrap-extract.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
etc.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe you are using `style` attributes?

Comment: @Bazzz Do you mean inline style in the html? I do not have any inline style in the html.

Comment: can you show the test page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it should be valid to me, however, the `meta` tag shouldn't be closed with `/>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

This *could* cause the `<head>` tag to close, but that's very unlikely.

Have you looked at the HTML in Google Chrome to see how it is being displayed in comparison with what the code should look like?

Comment: Thank you: the idea to look at the html in Chrome did not occur to me.  Actually Chrome did put the </head> before I put it. Since I have a PHP include to add the second part of the header (which is generic) and close the header this might be the problem.

Comment: Bingo. The PHP include to the end of my header was a file with an invisible BOM (refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8551908/190791). Switching to 'without BOM' fixed the problem.